# Namenode and Jobtracker information on Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

How can i get the following information on the Hadoop Cluster ?
1. namenode and jobtracker name
2. list of all nodes with their roles on the cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using cloudera based cluster and also working on EMR.
In both the clusters I can find the information from the configuration dir.
To get the namenode information go into core-site.xml file and look for the `fs.defaultFS` as @daemon12 said

Here is the straight way to get it.
For namenode information use the below command
`cat /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml | grep '8020'`

Here is the result

`<value>hdfs://10.872.22.1:8020</value>`
The values inside the value tag is the name node information.

Similarly to get the jobtracker information do the below

`cat /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml | grep '8032'`

Here is the result

`<value>10.872.12.32:8032</value>`

Again the jobtracker value is inside the value tag.

Generally the NN and JT information is used to run the Oozie jobs and this method will help you for that purpose.

DISCLAIMER: I am grepping the result of `cat` based on the namenode and jobtracker port number which is 8020 and 8032 respectively. This is widely known ports for NN and JT in Hadoop. If your organization uses a different one, please use that to get more appropriate result.

Answer (score 5):

To get namenode info:

```
    hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```

For jobtracker

```
    hdfs getconf -confKey yarn.resourcemanager.address.rm2
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with the command-line way of getting information, you can get the similar information in the browser also:

```
http://<namenode>:50070 (For in general hadoop informtion)
http://<namenode>:50030 (For JobTracker related information)
```

These are default ports. You can check [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/08/hadoop-default-ports-quick-reference/) for more information.

Comment: How to get the <namenode> name ?

Comment: Have a look at `core-site.xml` in your hadoop installation folder. You will find a property named `fs.default.name`. The value should give you <namenode>.

Answer (score 1):

With the correct granted authorization, (like  sudo -u hdfs ), you may try :

hdfs dfsadmin -report

Comment: This is showing the IP address of nodes in the cluster. How to get the hostnames with their roles in the cluster?

Comment: you can for example ssh to those servers and run a jps command (again with the correct rights) and check the java processes running : you should see which hadoop servers are running on which server.   I suppose you don't have acces to a gui manager (like hue, cloudera manager ...)  ?